# How to recursively expand an environment variable?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Assume the following:

`echo %MY_ENV_VAR%` expands to `%USERPROFILE%\some\path`
`echo %USERPROFILE%` expands to `C:\Users\MyUser`

My goal is to create an empty file at the following path: `C:\Users\MyUser\some\path\FOO.txt`.

I tried the following command: `type nul > %MY_ENV_VAR%\FOO.txt`

Unfortunately the output is an error which states *The system cannot find the path specified.*

I'm pretty certain this is because the shell is not recursively expanding `%MY_ENV_VAR%` and it's trying to find a literal path that begins with `%USERPROFILE%`.

How can I best accomplish my goal?

Comment: What does `echo %MY_ENV_VAR%` give you?

Comment: @nneonneo `%USERPROFILE%\some\path` and the output of `echo %USERPROFILE%` expands to `C:\Users\MyUser`

Comment: Ordinarily, Windows would have done this for you when setting up the environment block.  Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183575/m2-not-working-in-system-variable-path-but-in-user-variable-path-only http://superuser.com/questions/823190/are-there-rules-to-windows-7-environment-variable-names

Comment: One workaround would be to explicitly pass the command to a child instance of `cmd.exe` to force it to be reparsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rem Create the problem
set "MY_ENV_VAR=%%USERPROFILE%%\some\path"
echo %MY_ENV_VAR%

rem One solution
call set "MY_ENV_VAR=%MY_ENV_VAR%"
echo %MY_ENV_VAR%
```

In the `call` line, the parser will replace `%MY_ENV_VAR%` with the content of the variable, generating

```
call set "MY_ENV_VAR=%USERPROFILE%\some\path"
```

When this command is executed, the `call` will force a second parse phase, generating

```
set "MY_ENV_VAR=C:\Users\MyUser\some\path"
```

Of course, if `USERPROFILE` contains another variable reference, the process must be repeated.

**edited** - Added a "solution" to the "recursive" problem and placed all the code inside a subroutine.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Create the problem
    set "_1first=c:\users"
    set "_2second=%%_1first%%\test"
    set "_3third=%%_2second%%\so & me\path"
    set "_4fourth=%%_3third%%"

    set "MY_ENV_VAR=%%_4fourth%%"

    echo inner variables
    echo -----------------------------
    set _
    echo -----------------------------
    echo(

    echo "MY_ENV_VAR = [%MY_ENV_VAR%]"
    call :expandInnerVariables MY_ENV_VAR
    echo "MY_ENV_VAR = [%MY_ENV_VAR%]"
    goto :eof

:expandInnerVariables varName
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "aux=="
    for /l %%i in (0 1 100) do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if "!%~1!"=="" (
            endlocal & goto :endExpand
        ) else for /f "delims=" %%a in ("=!%~1!") do (
            endlocal & call set "%~1%%a"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            for /f "delims=" %%b in ("=!%~1!") do (
                endlocal & set "aux=%%b" & if %%a==%%b goto :endExpand
            )
        )
    )
    :endExpand
    endlocal & set "%~1%aux%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: If you can generalize it by wrapping the `call set ...` portion in a loop that executes while the output still contains a pattern that matches the regex  `%[^%]+%` i'll definitely mark this as the solution.  Note: you don't have to use a regex, was just a way to get my point across; I'm not sure if batch files even support regex.

Comment: I just found [the following site](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html#advanced) that does something similar with `CALL set` but at the end it recommends you use delayed expansion instead due to `CALL` being very slow in a loop as it tries to access the disk. I've tried to get delayed expansion to work but can't seem to figure it out.  If you can get the a for-loop that will expand an N-nested variable using delayed expansion that would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Thank you.  I've marked it as accepted but two things.  Does this only work as long as the variable less than 100 deep?  Could you also describe how the `:expandInnerVariables` sub-function works?