# Can a predefined environment variable reference dynamically created environment variables?

Tags: windows

I want to create a persistent environment variable that references environment variables that are created in the command prompt.  This shows what I'm trying to do:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\testuser>echo %HTTP_PROXY%
http://%user%:test@%proxyip%:8080

C:\Users\testuser>set user=testuser

C:\Users\testuser>set password=testpass

C:\Users\testuser>set proxyip=10.20.10.100

C:\Users\testuser>echo %HTTP_PROXY%
http://%user%:test@%proxyip%:8080
```

I was expecting the final echo statement to print

```
http://testuser:testpass@10.20.10.100:8080
```

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: This post may look like a stupid one. But reason for this post is that I do not want to publish my password through windows environment variable and I want to define it in the command prompt where i am going to use the long url variable and don't want to memorize the long variable..

Comment: The Windows command prompt isn't DOS.

Comment: Environment variables are just strings. They are not dynamically evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't possible.  Environment variables are not recursively expanded.

What you could do is to create a batch script to set `HTTP_PROXY` for you.  It could even prompt you for the username, password and IP address to save you using `set`.

(If you need the batch script to get the template string from the environment for some reason, rather than using a hard-coded string, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765246/886887) explains how to do so.)

---

*Footnote:*

A persistent environment variable *can* reference other persistent environment variables, subject to some limitations.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184614/886887) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/823802/96662).

However, this only happens when the environment block is being built for a new process, not while the process is running.  (It also doesn't happen in the case where a new process inherits its environment from its parent, only when a brand new environment block is built.)

Comment: Thanks Harry for the suggestion. I am currently using another batch script to achieve the same. In fact I have split the environment variable at the points where it needs expanded and in the script I have concatenated the environment variables with the parameters passed to the script at run time.