# CMD enviroment variables not expanded in PATH variable

Tags: windows, cmd, path, environment-variables

I've some enviroment variables set in my sistem preferences (Windows 8.1). If i start cmd.exe and execute this commands:

```
C:\Users\Carlo>echo %GRAILS_HOME%
D:\Grails

C:\Users\Carlo>echo %GRADLE_HOME%
D:\Gradle

C:\Users\Carlo>echo %GROOVY_HOME%
D:\Groovy

C:\Users\Carlo>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLSClient\;
c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;
%GROOVY_HOME%\bin
```

Why the last three variables is not expanded in PATH?

Complete PATH variable is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Are they user variables or system variables?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184614/886887

Comment: If you define `PATH` as a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` in the user environment (i.e. `HKCU\Environment`), it can reference `REG_SZ` user environment values. winlogon.exe will append the user `PATH` to the system `PATH`. This also works for the compiler's `LIBPATH`, but not for some reason the linker's `LIB`. For historic reasons it also works for `OS2LIBPATH`, even though the OS/2 subsystem was removed way back in Windows 2000.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Johnston GRAILS_HOME, GRADLE_HOME and GROOVY_HOME are all system variables

Comment: @orion91, check `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"`. (System variables are defined in this registry key because the session manager, smss.exe, loads them first before starting winlogon.exe.) Make sure that the `GRAILS` values are defined as `REG_SZ`, not `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. `REG_SZ` values are added to the environment first, so you know they're always available for use in `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values such as `PATH`. Do not rely on the alphabetic order presented to you in regedit. Value enumeration order should be treated as arbitrary.

Comment: @eryksun all variables are REG_SZ type! Only variables: ComSpec, Path, PSModulePath, TEMP, TMP and windir are REG_EXPAND_SZ.

Comment: If i open EnvriomentVariables panel, open one of this variables and add-remove space, confirm changes and apply when CMD is re-opened all this variables are correctly expanded...

Comment: @orion91, the control panel environment variable dialog broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497) message to all top-level windows. Explorer responds by calling `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment`. That shouldn't be necessary, however. When the system boots, system variables should be expanded in winlogon.exe. Use a debugger or Process Explorer to check the environment of the winlogon.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables (EnvVars) are simply what their name state: *variables*; They have a name and a value (in Windows the value is a string).

So in your example the name is `PATH` and the value is the string you listed. The OS (command interpreter) doesn't have any idea about the *semantics* of the EnvVar value so when it expands the var name it just shows its value. It doesn't analyze the value and recursively expand any other variables that may be there.

If variables are defined in other variables (something that I wouldn't recommend) is the consumer's job to expand all of them.

A common C function that deals with EnvVars (maybe this will help): [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So I can not use environment variables in my PATH? Right?
Just one question... Why the %SystemRoot% variable is properly expanded in the PATH variable?

Comment: Harry Johnston is right, everything that i said only applies to _user_ EnvVars. It seems that for system EnvVars, they **are** expanded recursively (I've tried up to 3 nesting levels). Sorry for the confusion.